# Basic chat server and client using WebSocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, socket.io

Based on [Node.js in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/node-js-in-action) (Manning Publications) chapter 2 *"Building a Multi-room Chat Application"*, I've taken the model they presented (which is all typical ES5 and jQuery) and completely rewrote it using ES6 and adding a bit of functionality, as well as JSDoc throughout.

While the functionality is mostly identical (I added a bit of new functionality as well), the code is vastly different, and I would like to ask if it could be improved further.

This is what it looks like:

[image: chat]

In general, am I using some decent patterns, or are you seeing some trends in my structure, functions and objects that stinks?

I will present both the server (native Node.js along with socket.io for WebSocket) and client-side code (regular ES6 along with jQuery) with some brief explanation.

---

## Server-side

### `./server.js`

This server is responsible for receiving HTTP requests, serving the requested static assets (or an error), and starting the chat server (presented in next section).

```
"use strict"
const http = require('http')
const fileSystem = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const mediaType = require("mime")
const chatServer = require('./lib/chat_server')

const fileCache = {}
const HTTP_SERVER_PORT = 3000
const HTTP_SUCCESS = 200
const HTTP_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND = 404

/**
 * Respond when requested resource is OK.
 * @param {Object} response - the response from HTTP server
 * @param {string} filePath - where the requested file is
 * @param {Object} fileContents - the contents of the requested file
 */
const httpSuccess = (response, filePath, fileContents) => {
  const contentType = mediaType.lookup(path.basename(filePath))
  response.writeHead(HTTP_SUCCESS, { 'Content-Type': contentType})
  response.end(fileContents)
}

/**
 * Respond when the requested resource is not found.
 * @param {Object} response
 */
const httpResourceNotFound = response => {
  response.writeHead(HTTP_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
  response.write('Error ' + HTTP_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND + ': ' + 'resource not found')
  response.end()
}

/**
 * Serve static files from server.
 * @param {Object} response
 * @param {string} absPath
 */
const httpServeStaticFile = (response, absPath) => {
  if (fileCache[absPath]) {
    httpSuccess(response, absPath, fileCache[absPath])
  }
  else {
    fileSystem.exists(absPath, exists => {
      if (exists) {
        fileSystem.readFile(absPath, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            httpResourceNotFound(response)
          }
          else {
            fileCache[absPath] = data
            httpSuccess(response, absPath, data)
          }
        })
      }
      else {
        httpResourceNotFound(response)
      }
    })
  }
}

/**
 * Get absolute file path from URL
 * @param {string} url
 * @returns {string}
 */
const getAbsolutePathFromUrl = url => {
  let filePath
  if (url === '/') {
    filePath = 'public/index.html'
  }
  else {
    filePath = 'public' + url
  }
  return './' + filePath
}

const httpServer = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const absPath = getAbsolutePathFromUrl(request.url)
  httpServeStaticFile(response, absPath)
})

/**
 * Start listening with the HTTP server and the chat server.
 */
const startServers = () => {
  httpServer.listen(HTTP_SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + HTTP_SERVER_PORT + ".")
  })
  chatServer.listen(httpServer)
}

startServers()
```

---

### `./lib/chat_server.js`

This code handles all the WebSocket interactions on the server. It has a number of listeners/handlers as well as emitters, all of which are documented. I think overall it is pretty simple.

In the original code from the book, all the functions were included in `exports.listen` and I thought that was quite messy, so I extracted all the various code into their own distinct functions and only included the calls in `exports.listen`, which I think makes it much more maintainable and easier to document.

```
"use strict"
const socketIo = require('socket.io')

let io
const nickNames = {}
const namesUsed = []
let guestNumber = 1
const currentRoom = {}

/**
 * Start the Socket.IO server.
 * @param {Object} server - a running Node.js HTTP server
 */
exports.listen = server => {
  /* start Socket.IO server, allowing it
  to piggyback on existing HTTP server */
  io = socketIo.listen(server)
  io.set('log level', 1)
  /* define how each user connection will be handled */
  io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
    const EMIT_TO = 'rooms'
    guestNumber = assignGuestName(socket, guestNumber, nickNames, namesUsed)
    handleGetCurrentUserNickname(socket)
    joinDefaultRoom(socket)
    handleMessageBroadcasting(socket)
    handleNameChangeAttempts(socket, nickNames, namesUsed)
    handleRoomJoining(socket)
    handleClientDisconnection(socket)
    socket.on(EMIT_TO, () => {
      socket.emit(EMIT_TO, io.sockets.manager.rooms)
    })
  })
}

/**
 * Emit user's current nickname.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 */
const handleGetCurrentUserNickname = socket => {
  socket.on('getCurrentUserNickname', () => {
    socket.emit('currentUserNameResult', {
      nickName: nickNames[socket.id]
    })
  })
}

/**
 * Assign user a guest name.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 * @param {Number} guestNumber - the global current/last guest number assigned
 * @param {Object} nickNames - the global list of connection IDs and their nicknames
 * @param {Array} namesUsed - the global list of all nicknames used
 * @returns {Number} - the guestNumber incremented by 1
 */
const assignGuestName = (socket, guestNumber, nickNames, namesUsed) => {
  const name = 'Guest' + guestNumber
  nickNames[socket.id] = name
  socket.emit('nameResult', {
    success: true,
    name: name
  })
  namesUsed.push(name)
  return guestNumber + 1
}

/**
 * Make user join the default room.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 */
const joinDefaultRoom = socket => {
  joinRoom(socket, 'Lobby')
}

/**
 * Join a chat room and notify the user and other users that a room was joined.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 * @param {string} room - the name of the room to join
 */
const joinRoom = (socket, room) => {
  socket.join(room)
  currentRoom[socket.id] = room
  socket.emit('joinResult', { room: room })
  socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', {
    text: nickNames[socket.id] + ' has joined ' + room + '.'
  })
  informOfUsersInRoom(socket, room)
}

/**
 * Inform user joining a room of the users present in the room.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 * @param {string} room - the name of the room to join
 */
const informOfUsersInRoom =(socket,room) => {
  const usersInRoom = io.sockets.clients(room)
  if (usersInRoom.length > 1) {
    let usersInRoomSummary = 'Users currently in ' + room + ': '
    for (let i in usersInRoom) {
      const userSocketId = usersInRoom[i].id
      if (userSocketId != socket.id) {
        if (i > 0) {
          usersInRoomSummary += ', '
        }
        usersInRoomSummary += nickNames[userSocketId]
      }
    }
    usersInRoomSummary += '.'
    socket.emit('message', { text: usersInRoomSummary })
  }
}

/**
 * Handle name-change attempts.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 * @param {Object} nickNames - the global list of connection IDs and their nicknames
 * @param {Array} namesUsed - the global list of all nicknames used
 */
const handleNameChangeAttempts = (socket, nickNames, namesUsed) => {
  socket.on('nameAttempt', (name) => {
    if (name.indexOf('Guest') == 0) {
      socket.emit('nameResult', {
        success: false,
        message: 'Names cannot begin with "Guest".'
      })
    }
    else {
      if (namesUsed.indexOf(name) == -1) {
        var previousName = nickNames[socket.id]
        var previousNameIndex = namesUsed.indexOf(previousName)
        namesUsed.push(name)
        nickNames[socket.id] = name
        delete namesUsed[previousNameIndex]
        socket.emit('nameResult', {
          success: true,
          name: name
        })
        socket.broadcast.to(currentRoom[socket.id]).emit('message', {
          text: previousName + ' is now known as ' + name + '.'
        })
      }
      else {
        socket.emit('nameResult', {
          success: false,
          message: 'Name "' + name + '" is already in use.'
        })
      }
    }
  })
}

/**
 * Send chat messages.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 */
const handleMessageBroadcasting = socket => {
  socket.on('message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.to(message.room).emit('message', {
      text: nickNames[socket.id] + ': ' + message.text
    })
  })
}

/**
 * Joins a room if it already exists, or creates it and joins if it doesn't.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 */
const handleRoomJoining = socket => {
  socket.on('join', room => {
    socket.leave(currentRoom[socket.id])
    joinRoom(socket, room.newRoom)
  })
}

/**
 * Clean-up after a user disconnects.
 * @param {Object} socket - the user's client connection
 */
const handleClientDisconnection = socket => {
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const nickName = nickNames[socket.id]
    const nameIndex = namesUsed.indexOf(nickName)
    delete namesUsed[nameIndex]
    delete nickNames[socket.id]
    socket.broadcast.to(currentRoom[socket.id]).emit('message', {
      text: nickName + ' has disconnected.'
    })
  })
}
```

---

## Client-side

### `./public/index.html`

Just for reference, this is the HTML that the client-side code interacts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="room-name-header"></div>
    <div id="room-list-side-nav"></div>
    <div id="room-messages"></div>
    <form id="user-message-send-form">
      <input id="user-message-input-field" />
      <input id="send-button" type="submit" value="Send" />
      <div id="help">
        Chat commands:
        <ul>
          <li>Change nickname: <code>/nick [nickname]</code></li>
          <li>Join/create room: <code>/join [room]</code></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/chat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/js/chat_ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### `./public/js/chat.js`

This `Chat` class is a middle man of sorts between the `chat_server` and the jQuery GUI. Its methods use WebSocket to emit messages to the `chat_server`, while the jQuery parts (following this) handle most of the listening for WebSocket.

```
"use strict"

class Chat {
  /**
   * Handle the chat functionality.
   * @param {Object} socket - The socket assigned to the user's web client
   * @constructor
   */
  constructor(socket) {
    this.socket = socket
  }

  /**
   * Send message to a room.
   * @param {string} room - The room where the message is to be posted
   * @param {string} text - The message to be posted
   */
  sendMessage(room, text) {
    const message = {
      room: room,
      text: text
    }
    this.socket.emit('message', message)
  }

  /**
   * Get user's current nickname.
   */
  getCurrentUserNickname() {
    this.socket.emit('getCurrentUserNickname')
    this.socket.on('currentUserNameResult', response => {
      const nickName = response.nickName
      return nickName.toString()
    })
  }

  /**
   * Change the room the user is in.
   * @param {string} room - The name of the room to change to (i.e. join)
   */
  changeRoom(room) {
    const newRoom = { newRoom: room }
    this.socket.emit('join', newRoom)
  }

  /**
   * Handle processing of chat commands.
   * @param {string} command - A potential command string from user
   * @returns {string} - Whether the command was successful
   */
  processCommand(command) {
    const words = command.split(' ')
    // parse command from first word
    command = words[0]
      // account for the starting slash `/`
      .substring(1, words[0].length)
      .toLowerCase()
    let errorMessage = null
    switch(command) {
      case 'join':
        words.shift();
        const room = words.join(' ')
        this.changeRoom(room)
        break
      case 'nick':
        words.shift()
        const name = words.join(' ')
        this.socket.emit('nameAttempt', name)
        this.getCurrentUserNickname()
        break
      default:
        errorMessage = 'Unrecognized command: /' + command
        break
    }
    if (errorMessage) {
      return errorMessage
    }
  }
}
```

---

### `./public/js/chat_ui.js`

This section of the original code was the typical tangled mess we've come to expect from jQuery. Thankfully, the large majority of it I was able to convert to use ES6 arrow functions, except for the function in the `.click()` event in `allowClickingRoomNameToJoin()` function (hence you will notice the `TODO` comment there; if you have any suggestions in that respect let me know).

Overall I think it reads a lot easier like this, I again extracted all those in-line functions to their respective functions to make them easier to document and maintain. This is my first experience with jQuery so I feel especially sure that this part of the code could be improved a lot still.

```
"use strict"

$(document).ready(() => {

  // jQuery selectors
  const $roomNameHeader = $('#room-name-header')
  const $roomListSideNav = $('#room-list-side-nav')
  const $roomMessages = $('#room-messages')
  const $userMessageSendForm = $('#user-message-send-form')
  const $userMessageInputField = $('#user-message-input-field')

  const socket = io.connect()
  const chat = new Chat(socket)

  /**
   * Run the main functionality of the client.
   */
  const clientMain = () => {
    socket.on('nameResult', displayNameChangeResults)
    socket.on('joinResult', displayRoomJoinResults)
    socket.on('message', displayReceivedMessage)
    socket.on('rooms', displayAvailableRoomsList)
    socket.on('currentUserNameResult', setNickname)

    let nickName = chat.getCurrentUserNickname()

    /**
     * Request list of rooms intermittently
     */
    setInterval(() => {
      socket.emit('rooms')
    }, 1000)

    $userMessageInputField.focus()

    /**
     * Allow submitting the form to send a chat message.
     */
    $userMessageSendForm.submit(() => {
      processUserInput(chat)
      return false
    })
  }

  const setNickname = result => {
    this.nickName = result.nickName
  }

  /**
   * Format user-submitted content to display in chat.
   * @param {string} message - The raw content from user
   * @returns {*|jQuery}
   */
  const divEscapedContentElement = message => {
    return $('<div class="user-message"></div>').text(message)
  }

  /**
   * Format system-submitted content to display in chat.
   * @param {string} message - The raw content from system
   * @returns {*|jQuery}
   */
  const divSystemContentElement = message => {
    return $('<div class="system-message"></div>').html(message)
  }

  /**
   * Route raw input to the correct channel.
   * @param {Object} chat - The applicable chat application
   */
  const processUserInput = chat => {
    const message = $userMessageInputField.val()
    if (isCommand(message)) {
      const systemMessage = chat.processCommand(message)
      if (systemMessage) {
        $roomMessages.append(divSystemContentElement(systemMessage))
      }
    }
    else {
      chat.sendMessage($roomNameHeader.text(), message)
      $roomMessages.append(divEscapedContentElement(nickName + ': ' + message))
      $roomMessages.scrollTop($roomMessages.prop('scrollHeight'))
    }
    $userMessageInputField.val('')
  }

  /**
   * Detect whether the given raw input is a command.
   * @param {string} message - The raw input
   * @returns {boolean} - Whether the raw input is considered a command
   */
  const isCommand = message => {
    return message.charAt(0) === '/'
  }

  /**
   * Display name changes.
   * @param {Object} result
   */
  const displayNameChangeResults = result => {
    let message
    if (result.success) {
      message = 'You are now known as ' + result.name + '.'
    }
    else {
      message = result.message
    }
    $roomMessages.append(divSystemContentElement(message))
  }

  /**
   * Display room joins.
   * @param {Object} result
   */
  const displayRoomJoinResults = result => {
    $roomNameHeader.text(result.room)
    $roomMessages.append(divSystemContentElement('Room changed'))
  }

  /**
   * Display a new message.
   * @param {string} message
   */
  const displayReceivedMessage = message => {
    const newMessage = $('<div></div>').text(message.text)
    $roomMessages.append(newMessage)
  }

  /**
   * Display available rooms.
   * @param {Array} rooms
   */
  const displayAvailableRoomsList = rooms => {
    $roomListSideNav.empty()
    for (let room in rooms) {
      room = room.substring(1, room.length)
      if (room !== '') {
        $roomListSideNav.append(divEscapedContentElement(room))
      }
    }
    allowClickingRoomNameToJoin()
  }

  /**
   * Allow clicking of a room name in room list to join said room.
   */
  const allowClickingRoomNameToJoin = () => {
    // TODO look for a better way to scope `this` with ES6 to eliminate `function()`
    $roomListSideNav.find('div').click(function() {
      chat.processCommand('/join ' + $(this).text())
      $userMessageInputField.focus()
    })
  }

  clientMain()

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to the TODO comment, I would suggest something like this:

```js
const allowClickingRoomNameToJoin = () => {
    // TODO look for a better way to scope `this` with ES6 to eliminate `function()`
  $roomListSideNav.find('div').click(e => {
    chat.processCommand('/join ' + $(e.target).text())
    $userMessageInputField.focus()
  })
}
```

This removes the anonymous function declaration and replaces it with an ES6+ arrow function as requested.